# How to force jQuery.text() working even after manual updating the TEXTAREA value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I've just noticed, that the jQuery [`text(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) method only sets the content of a `TEXTAREA`, if if has not been updated manually. For example (also on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/automatix/1ovdLrxb/)):

```js
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   $('#myText').text(Date.now); 
});
```

```html
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
<button id="myButton">Go!</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Now when I click on <kbd>Go!</kbd>, the content of the `TEXTAREA` gets updated with the current timestamp. I also can do it multiple times. Working. But if I manually change the text (e.g. by deleting or adding a character), it stops working.

I also tried out the `val(...)` method. It works as expected, regardless of manual changes on the text field.

**How to get `jQuery.text(...)` working after manual changes?**

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` here?

Comment: *"I also tried out the val(...) method. It works as expected, regardless of manual changes on the text field."* Then why are you using `text`?

Comment: Similar question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927593/cant-update-textarea-with-javascript-after-writing-to-it-manually

Comment: @j08691 The `.val(...)` is intended for the `value` attribute. And the `TEXTAREA` has an inner text. So it would make sense to use `.text(...)` for it I just want to know, why it doesn't work as it should or/and whether I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please see the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700848/how-to-force-jquery-text-working-even-after-manual-updating-the-textarea-value?noredirect=1#comment82391246_47700848).

Comment: @automatix: `val` isn't intended for the `value` **attribute**, it's intended for the form control's *current value* (the `value` attribute isn't the current value, not even for an `input`; it's the *default* value). What you're doing wrong is using `text`, not `val`. `val` is how you set the value of a `textarea`. If you have any doubt that `val` correctly sets the value of the `textarea`, here's proof: https://jsfiddle.net/msrgzozm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to suggest you know you can use `val` but are choosing not to. So I tried various options, but I don't think you can reliably use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set a textarea.

So, since the correct way to set the value of a `textarea` is to use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), use `val`. :-) If you do that, it works regardless of whether the `textarea` is edited by the user:

```js
$('#myButton').click(function() {
   $('#myText').val(Date.now); 
});
```

```html
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
<button id="myButton">Go!</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```